# Can I fly a quadcopter over 50m above a property I don't own according to the UK's Dronecode?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, caa-uk-regulations

I have a question about the law on flying quadcopters equipped with a camera in the UK. The dronesafe.uk website states that drones are not to be flown within 50m of any property or people that you do not have control over. Does this mean horizontally or both horizontally and vertically? Basically is it legal to fly a quadcopter above a property that I do not own as long as it is 50m or above the property?

Comment: Be aware that the Dronecode is not law.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at page 2 of the "[Dronecode](http://dronesafe.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Dronecode.pdf)". The illustration makes it quite obvious that the 50 metres refers to both vertical and horizontal distance:

[image]

Comment: I know it's obvious but the diagram on the right made me have second thoughts about if i was right. The only reason i asked is because i didn't want to break the law. Thanks for clearing things up for me.

Comment: @Cabe 50 meters distance is for **isolated** buildings or people. In build up areas (towns, cities, campsites and crowds), you are NOT allowed to fly over, but must stay 150 metres horizontal distance away.